# Create dynamic type with keys coming from array state in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to create a dynamic type using a state, which is type of string array.

The state I would like to use is as follows:

```
const [data, setData] = useState<string[]>(['orange', 'apple'])
```

And I want to obtain the following type after the operation:

```
type Output = {orange: string, apple: string}
```

This should work dynamic so that any state update will also be reflected on the type.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"any state update will also be reflected on the type"* - do you want the type to change during runtime? This would not be possible. Can you show us how you intend to use this type?

Comment: If I'm understanding you right you are saying that whenever we update the array, this type output object should also update. if that is right than its easy create a new state for type object and update it everytime alongside data array, I can post an answer if you want me too

Comment: Oh, I got that what I want is inapplicable since TypeScript compiles into JavaScript before runtime thus it would not be possible, so state being a runtime thing and type being a build time thing I think there is no way.

What I wanted is to use react-datasheet-grid package for a datasheet UI but with dynamic number of columns. I wanted to provide a correct type for my data.